# How to clear cache for specific sites using code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, browser-cache

When my website is loading, I am storing JS and CSS in cache for decreasing the load of the page.

After updating the code on server, I need to load that JS and CSS code again in cache, so how it is possible to clear that cache using code? And this cache should be cleared once after uploading the code on the server.

Any suggestions will be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `?v=1` at the end of the URL, and keep on increasing the number, whenever you want to clear the cache.

It changes the URL and tells browser think, this is a new file.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com.com/style.css?v=1"/>
```

This is what, StackOverflow does.

Stackoverflow code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=9df52c12ea50">
```